# How to use $(xterm -e) containing pipe?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to tail a file in a new xterm shell and then kill the tail once it sees the phrase "Tailkill2".

```
xterm -e "tail -F $PWD/$LOGFILE | { sed "/Tailkill2/ q" && pkill -P $$ tail ;} &"
```

Why doesn't this work?

By the way, is there a way to wrap the -e argument in something other than quotes so it doesn't get confusing?

Answer (score 0):

There are some parts you still need to quote to make sure that this command you want to send to the shell summoned by `xterm` is what it would exactly get. And it's easy to fix it by using single quotes. Consider placing variables around double quotes as well to prevent word splitting and possible pathname expansions.

```
xterm -e 'tail -F "$PWD/$LOGFILE" | { sed "/Tailkill2/q" && pkill -P "$$" tail; } &'
```